# Deploy fails on CI/CD Github (webhooks) to AWS

Tags: docker, github, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am doing CI/CD for a Wordpress stack in Docker from Github to AWS. I have my CodePipeline and the workflow is working in Source and Build steps but Deploy failed with:

```
Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0d474d15cf9d1f66b'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-0d474d15cf9d1f66b] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
```

When I check the Application Enviroment log I get:

```
Incorrect application version "code-pipeline-1590440852068-BuildArtifact-f90b1b39-4b30-4414-b0ae-d9f59df3b6b3" (deployment 13). Expected version "Sample Application" (deployment 1).
```

I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without knowing details of your template. But for the error message , it seems to be something related to the configuration in Codedeploy. Regards.

Comment: flávio queiroz, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).